# PHP - Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP site and I am trying to create a custom page.

I am getting a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()`

When I run this code:

```
<?php
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```

This is the url:

```
https://[url of my site]/lesson1.php
```

I know the reason why. A normal worpress page url looks like this:

```
https://[url of my site]/index.php/lesson1
```

I think the pages are stored in a database and the index.php is the resource that gets them somehow.

So the question is, if I want to create a PHP file, which is separate from the WP install, how can I access functions, such as `wp_get_current_user()` ?

Comment: where is wp-config.php?

Comment: @JaydeepPandya It is located here: /public_html/wp-config.php

Comment: No, I am asking to include it in your custom page; after that wp_get_current_user() function will work..

Comment: @JaydeepPandya `wp-config.php` is nothing more then a` configuration file`. it  only contains database and various settings, `wp-config.php` it self get's included into other files. Main file is : `wp-load.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress's wp-load.php file contains all of it functions / connections , you can do it with the following way and include the main wordpress file into your php file to get wordpress functions into your file.

```
<?php 
 define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
 require('./wp-load.php');
?>
```

Comment: That looks like a good solution. For the same of speed, is there anything else that I can disable besides the theme?

Comment: that is basic settings for disabling the theme files. you will be able to work better with that. Just use the functions you need so it will be more quick to load.

Comment: Should I do require_once() instead of require() ?

Comment: does not make difference, as you are only going to include it only once , so you can use either `require` or `require_once`

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating page on the root, you will require wp-load.php file, so include it in your page.

```
require( 'wp-load.php' );
```

Hope this will help you.